# Drill Through Report for new window

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have got one problem with MS Reporting Services. I created a asp.net page with report viewer control. The report viewer control renders the report on the MS Reporting Services. I created an action in textbox within the report. This action is "go to report". This action makes that the another report is called. In my case, I want to create a new window with the called report. But I don't want to use go to url. Because I don't want to show my parameters within url. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm interesting question. As far as I know this isn't possible, at least up to 2008R2. Perhaps someone's answer will tell us otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to test this at the moment, but I think setting the `HyperlinkTarget` property to `_blank` on the `ReportViewer` should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.hyperlinktarget.aspx